# How to save this JSON Object to Array List in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I'm having troubles finding a way how to parse this JSONObject on Java:

```
{"market_cap":[[1518987267000,183700781183],
               [1518987567000,183687424480],
               [1518987868000,183687424480],
               .
               .
               .
               [1519080954726,7730730000]]}
```

This is the full json: [JSON](http://coincap.io/history/1day/BTC)

I´m looking for save these data on a List Array...

I have updated my full function:

```
static String urlJsonArry2 = "http://coincap.io/history/1day/BTC";
private JSONObject responseJsonObject;


private void GettingDataGraph(){

    progressDialog.setMessage("Getting Data");
    progressDialog.show();

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry2,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    try {

                        ArrayList<Object> MARKET_CAP_ARRAY_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

                        JSONArray marketCapArray = responseJsonObject.optJSONArray("volume");

                        for (int i=0; i< marketCapArray.length(); i++){

                            JSONArray array1 = (JSONArray) marketCapArray.get(i);

                            for (int j=0; j < array1.length(); j++){

                                MARKET_CAP_ARRAY_LIST.add(array1.get(j));

                            }

                        }

                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(MARKET_CAP_ARRAY_LIST));
                        progressDialog.dismiss();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, "ERROR " + e.getMessage());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR " + error.getMessage());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

}
```

My updated logcat is this:

```
D/Volley: [1] 5.onErrorResponse: ListMain
D/ListMain: ERROR org.json.JSONException: Value {"volume":[[1518987267000,9151900000],[1518987567000,9157160000],[1518987868000,9169080000],[1518988166000,9161370000],[1518988467000,9154150000],[1518988765000,9144130000],[1518989067000,9128060000],[1518989366000,9117040000],[1518989665000,9113130000],[1518989965000,9094710000],[1518990267000,9110340000],[1518990567000,9144620000],[1518990868000,9168270000],[1518991167000,9179440000],[1518991467000,9181180000],[1518991767000,9175010000],[1518992067000,9175640000],[1518992366000,9161110000],[1518992667000,9140220000],[1518992966000,9146430000],[1518993266000,9164780000],[1518993567000,9136680000],[1518993866000,9087550000],[1518994167000,9035050000],[1518994466000,8991310000],[1518994766000,8990680000],[1518995067000,8973400000],[1518995367000,8941170000],[1518995667000,8895200000],[1518995966000,8853810000],[1518996267000,8821540000],[1518996566000,8778680000],[1518996867000,8778560000],[1518997167000,8802030000],[1518997467000,8808330000],[1518997767000,8793550000],[1518998068000,8778190000],[1518998367000,8744010000],[1518998667000,8730850000],[1518998967000,8739700000],[1518999266000,8708270000],[1518999566000,8692760000],[1518999867000,8696210000],[1519000167000,8691320000],[1519000467000,8704830000],[1519000768000,8701960000],[1519001067000,8703500000],[1519001366000,8690490000],[1519001666000,8654650000],[1519001966000,8645390000],[1519002266000,8642730000],[1519002567000,8594570000],[1519002867000,8634390000],[1519003166000,8671810000],[1519003466000,8673840000],[1519003769000,8680670000],[1519004068000,8676080000],[1519004369000,8672160000],[1519004666000,8635240000],[1519004969000,8601340000],[1519005266000,8610940000],[1519005567000,8609810000],[1519005869000,8623850000],[1519006173000,8627350000],[1519006467000,8593110000],[1519006765000,8582360000],[1519007066000,8558920000],[1519007367000,8520250000],[1519007666000,8534120000],[1519007969000,8565770000],[1519008268000,8568240000],[1519008568000,8568010000],[1519008867000,8551680000],[1519009168000,8520880000],[1519009467000,8505580000],[1519009769000,8499980000],[1519010069000,8460400000],[1519010368000,8443030000],[1519010667000,8435930000],[1519010969000,8385870000],[1519011267000,8336820000],[1519011567000,8314420000],[1519011866000,8306510000],[1519012167000,8289780000],[1519012467000,8265550000],[1519012767000,8230840000],[1519013067000,8198170000],[1519013368000,8184000000],[1519013668000,8183500000],[1519013967000,8177700000],[1519014268000,8173580000],[1519014567000,8169000000],[1519014868000,8156480000],[1519015166000,8142310000],[1519015466000,8135780000],[1519015767000,8146410000],[1519016067000,8142550000],[1519016368000,8121680000],[1519016668000,8100770000],[1519016967000,8107950000],[1519017268000,8058870000],[1519017566000,7990860000],[1519017867000,7953970000],[1519018169000,7918280000],[1519018467000,7881990000],[1519018768000,7823290000],[1519019067000,7815010000],[1519019366000,7808360000],[1519019667000,7784880000],[1519019968000,7749460000],[1519020267000,7735900000],[1519020566000,7734530000],[1519020865000,7718370000],[1519021166000,7699210000],[1519021467000,7685120000],[1519021767000,7677750000],[1519022067000,7660540000],[1519022365000,7627040000],[1519022666000,7621670000],[1519022966000,7620360000],[1519023267000,7613420000],[1519023568000,7583250000],[1519023867000,7563660000],[1519024167000,7581690000],[1519024467000,7592450000],[1519024767000,7575950000],[1519025068000,7623950000],[1519025368000,7705190000],[1519025666000,7750020000],[1519025967000,7794050000],[1519026267000,7820790000],[1519026567000,7814480000],[1519026868000,7819060000],[1519027167000,7811230000],[1519027467000,7812310000],[1519027766000,7806300000],[1519028069000,7717960000],[1519028367000,7717970000],[1519028666000,7739410000],[1519028967000,7770270000],[1519029267000,7787760000],[1519029567000,7778010000],[1519029867000,7753830000],[1519030166000,7743590000],[1519030467000,7744180000],[1519030767000,7712770000],[1519031066000,7684790000],[1519031367000,7648400000],[1519031667000,7630540
```

I'm getting a **onErrorResponse**

In case someone is interested...this code works good for this array:

```
ArrayList<Object> MARKET_CAP_ARRAY_LIST = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("market_cap");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray array1 = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);

                for (int j=0; j < array1.length(); j++){

                    MARKET_CAP_ARRAY_LIST.add(array1.get(j));
                    Log.d("ARRAY: ", String.valueOf(MARKET_CAP_ARRAY_LIST));

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks...

Comment: Please post some more of the error message as it seems to be truncated. And why does your code say `"market_cap"` but the error says `"volume"`?

Comment: `new JSONArray("market_cap")`?? The text `market_cap` (10 characters) is not a JSON array.

Comment: @Ken Y-N  I don't know why on my browser the json is "market_cap", but on Android Studio the response is "volume"...

Comment: `new JSONArray("market_cap");` what do you think this does?

Comment: Is the start for the Array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse  [JSON](http://coincap.io/history/1day/BTC)   like this.

```
private void parseJsonObject(JSONObject responseJsonObject) throws JSONException {

    ArrayList<Object> MARKET_CAP_ARRAY_LIST = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray marketCapArray = responseJsonObject.optJSONArray("market_cap");

    for (int i=0; i< marketCapArray.length(); i++){

        JSONArray array1 = (JSONArray) marketCapArray.get(i);

        for (int j=0; j < array1.length(); j++){

            MARKET_CAP_ARRAY_LIST.add(array1.get(j));

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code but I´m still getting a **onErrorResponse** . Please look my updated code

Comment: It works now with this code...thanks!... @yatin-deokar

Answer (score 0):

```
private class JsonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String url ;

    public JsonAsyncTask(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        processApiResponse(url);
        return null;
    }

    private void processApiResponse(String url) {
        try {
            URL jsonUrl = new URL(url);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonUrl.openStream()));

            String inputLine;

            StringBuilder jsonStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                jsonStringBuilder.append(inputLine);
            in.close();

            String jsonString = jsonStringBuilder.toString();

            Volume volume = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Volume.class);

            System.out.println(volume);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The POJO classes

```
private class Volume {
    ArrayList<VolumeObject> market_cap;
    ArrayList<VolumeObject> volume;
}

private class VolumeObject extends ArrayList<Double> {

}
```

You can use

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
```

to add Gson in your project.

And to call the AsyncTask in an activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy);

    JsonAsyncTask task = new JsonAsyncTask("http://coincap.io/history/1day/BTC");
    task.execute();
}
```

I hope this helps

Note: For the network operation you can use any other library. Whereas retrofit is preferred by me.

Comment: I´m using Volley for the moment...I tried with gson but I don't had luck...

Comment: What are the problems you are facing using Gson? I can give you a complete working code with Gson

Comment: the variable "jsonString" what is exactly?...is the url from Json?...I get this response: "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING"

Comment: jsonString is the content of the URL, i.e. the actual JSON strung.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work..."Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING"

Comment: Please check the updated answer. If you need anything else please let me know